How to prevent bracket bolts through fascia (and flashing) from leaking
I'm having a flat roof on a deck/patio area above a bedroom replaced. I'm getting IB Deckshield installed, and using fascia mount railings to avoid putting penetrations in the top surface. The roofers are providing a 9" fascia flashing. I plan to bolt brackets to hold guard rails through this (specifically the Fortress Fe26 fascia brackets here). Hopefully the diagrams make it clear.

I'm worried about water ingress either behind the bracket or through the bolt hole, reaching the wood joist through the hole I will need to drill in the flashing.
What would be the best methods to keep my rim joist from getting wet?
For the bracket I'm considering butyl tape, but would a different sealant be better?
For the bolt, it seems like I either need a wide brimmed bolt and a single rubber washer, or bolt -> rubber washer -> metal washer -> rubber washer -> bracket. Is that overkill or is there a better way?

Well I ended up using butyl on the back of the bracket and behind the metal bolt covers included with the bracket. The bolt covers have a metal threaded cover that should prevent most ingress as far as I can tell.
A few of these are installed in an areas where I will have access to check how they are holding up over the years.
